# autmatic urldecode asp.net

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, url-rewriting, urlencode, urldecode

i have this url in a c# web application, framework 4

/en/song/august+burns+red/1%2f16%2f2011

my problem is that in the rewrite module, the url of the request comes as

/en/song/august+burns+red/1/16/2011

this is wrong, becouse i dont do any server.urldecode, and i need to have the "1%2f16%2f2011" as it comes, not decoded, also becouse i split the url by the '/' character... is asp.net urldecoding automatically? how can i disable that? i tried to sniff the  httprequest, maybe was the browser that urldecoded the slashes, but it is not so, i'm sure is asp.net or iis7

Comment: The decode is automatically done inside the url class. The most easy way is to change your date format using the '-' and not the '/'

Comment: either you remove the `date` in your **route** so the url would end up like `/en/song/august+burns+red/?date=1%2f16%2f2011` or you need to change the input format.

Comment: that is not a date, its the title of the song (was passed a date, but a title, as the artist, can have %2f inside) i don't wanna do anyreplace becouse if i use - or ! for replace the "/", when someone use - ! they will become "/". there are many reasons for have passing the exact value from the db in the url rewrite. if there is no way to disable the decode of the slashes, it is really ridicoulus from microsoft.

Comment: Can you not set up a rewrite rule that will find anything after /song/ and class that as a song name? so route to song.aspx?songname=blah/blah/blah - regardless of it being decoded it should still work?

Comment: no, the url are yet indexed, and however, i wanted the url rewrite for dont use the GET parameters. i dont understand why these characters should be auto urldecoded. in asp.net forum nobody answered me. i have no words.